# - assembly sse - segmentation fault - move a matrix row in another matrix

Tags: c, assembly, matrix

I have two matrix nxn, A and B.

A=[1  2  3  4 ;   5  6  7  8 ;   9  10 11 12 ;   13 14 15 16]

B=[1 1 1 1 ;   1 1 1 1 ;   1 1 1 1 ;   1 1 1 1 ]

The two matrix are allocated as in float* in C.
From main.c , I call a procedure in assembly 'exportRow(A,B,n);'

In assembly,

```
    ...
    mov     eax,[ebp+a]
    mov     ebx,[ebp+b]
    mov     [xa],eax
    mov     [xb],ebx
    printps [xa],1
    printps [xb],1
    movaps  xmm0,[xa]
    movaps  [xb],xmm0        ;casuses segmentation fault
    ...
```

printps is a macro, it's only for print one location memory of xa and xb (they are dword).
I want to use xa and xb as pointer of matrix.

OUTPUT:

```
[1,2,3,4] 
[1,1,1,1]
SEGMENTATION FAULT
```

Why the last instruction causes segmentation fault? where is the problem?
If I replace [xb] with [xa] (only for test) at last instruction, I haven't nothing error.

--EDIT---

If I modify [xb], the modify should not affect also on B?

However,with a little modify: (actually xa and xb are resd and alligned at 32 bytes. )

```
 movaps  xmm0,[xa+16]
 movaps [xb],xmm0
 printps [xb],1
```

SEGMENTATION FAULT....

---EDIT ----

This is a little example of code:

```
int main(){
 int m=4;
 int n=4;
 float* A=malloc(sizeof(float)*m*n);
 float* B=malloc(sizeof(float)*m*n);
 for(int i=0;i<m*n;i++){
     A[i]=i;
     B[i]=1;
 }
 printMatrix(A,m,n);
 printMatrix(B,m,n);
 exportRow(A,B,n); //procedure assembly 
 printMatrix(B,m,n);
```

}

Assembly code:

```
section .data
   A equ 8
   B equ 12
   n equ 16
section .bss
   alignb 32
   xa resd 1
   alignb 32
   xb resd 1
section .text
global exportRow

exportRow: push ebp
           mov ebp,esp
           push ebx
           push esi
           push edi

           mov     eax,[ebp+a]
           mov     ebx,[ebp+b]
           mov     [xa],eax
           mov     [xb],ebx
           printps [xb],1
           printps [xa+16],1
           movaps  xmm0,[xa+16]
           movaps  [xb],xmm0        
           printps [xb],1

           pop edi
           pop esi
           pop ebx
           mov esp,ebp
           pop ebp
           ret
```

OUTPUT:

```
A=[1 2 3 4 ; 5 6 7 8 ; 9 10 11 12 ; 13 14 15 16]

B=[1 1 1 1 ; 1 1 1 1 ; 1 1 1 1 ; 1 1 1 1 ]

[1,1,1,1]
SEGMENTATION FAULT
```

case alignb 32:
if I get [xa+16] , I have the segmentation fault.

case alignb 16:
if I get [xa+16], I have [1 1 1 1], why? I was thinking that result was [5 6 7 8].

And another question (I think that two questions are correlated):
With the code in top of the post :

```
mov     eax,[ebp+a]
mov     ebx,[ebp+b]
mov     [xa],eax
mov     [xb],ebx
printps [xa],1
printps [xb],1
movaps  xmm0,[xa]
movaps  [xb],xmm0 
printps [xb],1
```

output:

```
A=[1 2 3 4 ; 5 6 7 8 ; 9 10 11 12 ; 13 14 15 16]

B=[1 1 1 1 ; 1 1 1 1 ; 1 1 1 1 ; 1 1 1 1 ]

[ 0.000000 1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 ]
[ 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 ]
[ 0.000000 1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 ]

B=[1.000000 1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    
1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    
1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    
1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000]
```

I have modified xb, but the matrix B is intact. why?

Comment: Probably just memory misalignment.

Comment: how do I align it? I test it

Comment: Yes, the problem was it!
changing [xb], because the changes did not also have an impact on the matrix B?

Answer (score 3):

xb does not have a memory address that is 16 byte aligned.  If you check the memory address in hex it is REQUIRED to always end in a 0.  If it does not you need to use movups rather than movaps.

It is nearly always better to simply align at 64-bytes, however.

On windows checkout: [_aligned_malloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Edit:  So looking at your .bss section you don't seem to be doing what you think you are doing.  You are copying the pointer stored at "EAX" to the address pointed to by the single byte "xa".  This can't possibly be correct.

You need to assure your original allocation is 16 byte aligned.  From there you can directly move one line of the matrix pointed to by A to B directly via a movaps to an xmm0 register and then another movaps from that register!

Edit 2:  In summary xa and xb are pointless.

```
movaps  xmm0,[eax+16]
movaps  [ebx],xmm0
```

Though the memory allocated by malloc MUST be 16 byte aligned ...

Comment: actually xa and xb are alligned at 32 bytes. making a small change:
 movaps  xmm0,[xa+16]
 movaps [xb],xmm0
 printps [xb],1

I obtain "SEGMENTATION FAULT"... [xa+16] is the second row of matrix (float) 4x4?

Comment: @user3661321 I'd be interested to see the pointer values.  Do you still get the crash when using movups? If you do the you haven't alloc'd the memory correctly, if not then the memory is not 32 bytes aligned!

Comment: @user3661321:  Why do you think malloc returns 32 byte aligned?  It might not.  Also ... did you try the movups experiment?

Comment: @user3661321: The matrices are not in the .bss section, don't forget!!

Comment: my goal is to have a variable X that points to the beginning of the memory block of the array, in this way I access easily to the position X [i].

Comment: How do it? [xa+16] does not the second row of A?

Comment: @user3661321: eax and ebx ARE the variables that point to the beginning of the matrices.